# How to apply a filter with a brush in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, photoshop-cs6

How can i apply a filter with a brush in Photoshop?

If i go into Photoshop -> Filter menu, there is a quite a large list of filters i can apply to an image. I would like to be able to apply these filters not to the whole image but to a part of it by painting on this image with a brush.

Comment: Look at this https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/photoshop-brushes-intro.html

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like  Why more and more tutorials resort only to videos nowadays? Do they think people can't read any more? I read what they have in written form, it does not really say "you can't use paint brush to apply filter effects" (unless i missed something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To my knowledge you can't put a filter on a brush in Photoshop. A    brush can have different textures, sizes and other options. A filter acts on the whole picture or your can make a selection first and then restrict the filter to only that selected part.
- If you don't want to use selection tools to set the selection consider doing a Quick Mask. With Quick Mask, you can use a brush to "paint" an overlay of mask over the area to be selected. Then apply the filter(s) as needed.
- I'll often use a combination of tools. Free form lasso or magnet lasso to get a general selection of the image area. Quick Mask mode and round hard brush to clean up the selection. Note Quick Mask works with black or white. Painting black adds to the selection, white removes from it.
- I love keyboard shortcuts for Quick Mask work; <kbd>q</kbd> quick mask    mode, <kbd>d</kbd> default black and white, <kbd>x</kbd> flips foreground/background colors. So bouncing on <kbd>x</kbd> will add or remove to your selection very quickly and give you a lot of control when getting your selection edge exactly where you want it.

Comment: Quick Masks is basically what i was looking for, maybe just a little bit more cumbersome than painting a filter directly on an image. I'm sure there is some logic to it, but i'm wondering why it is not possible to directly apply a filter effect with a brush.